# How to solve: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

Im trying to map my state , but it allways returns me this error, someone knows how to solve it ?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (mounted && userForm.length > 0) {
      console.log(userForm, 'campos:', userForm.fields);
      return;
    } else {
      setuserForm(JSON.parse(route.params.paramKey));
      console.log(userForm);
    }
  }, [userForm]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>COLLECTION :</Text>



        {userForm.length > 0 ? (
          userForm.map((item) => (          
            <Text key={uuid.v4()}>{item.fields}</Text>
          ))
        ) : (
          <Text key={uuid.v4()}> Loading ...</Text>
        )}

      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

what I'm trying to do is render all my fields and then handle the following types.

Comment: Any reason why `toString` is async? `await item.fields.toString()`

Comment: @Drag13 I thought the keys prop would need to be an string instead of an object

Comment: It need to be a string, but makes no sense to use `async`/`await` in this case, you should just do `toString`. Also, I think would be better to use the index of it as a key, for example: `userForm.map((item, index) => <Text key={index}>Test</Text>`.

Comment: @EsdrasXavier I changed the code removing the async, but it still returning me the same error

Comment: @GuilhermeCavenaghi Could you please provide the JSON value as example? Don't need to have the real data, just the structure. I think you are trying to render some object instead of the text it self.

Comment: In case `item.fields` is not a string/number - it's not valid. I asume it's an array, right? `await JSON.parse` is also not needed, JSON.parse is sync

Comment: @EsdrasXavier my console.log is not  working just returning me the error

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to render `item.field as node`. However, seems that this is an array, so you need to map it one more time.
For example, if it contains `strings` it might looks like this:

```
  <Text key={uuid.v4()}>{item.fields?.concat('')}</Text>
```

In case filds contains objects you have to map it to the new component, like this:

```
  <Text key={uuid.v4()}>{item.fields?.map((field, i)=> <div key={i}>{field.someProp}</div>}</Text>
```

In case you don't know what is inside the fields, check the Network tab in the ChromeDeveloperTools (F12) or use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: I tried to use the way that you did (it's a string) , but it didnt work , I thing that my use Effect is not working because it's not returning me anything in the console, just displaying the error

Comment: Ok, please provide more code and the error from console.  
@GuilhermeCavenaghi